# md-select doesn't trigger ngModelChange or change events

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I have this code:

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="model" (change)="updateModel()" 
(ngModelChange)="model=$event;updateModel()"> [...] <md-select>
```

but when I update the model programmatically, neither (change) nor (ngModelChange) 
 are fired 'cause updateModel() is never called.

Comment: Show your `updateModel` *function*.

Comment: it is a banal console.log...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your full code, but if the md-select is inside the FORM tag, it would not work.

I tested the example from material doc, and (change)/(ngModelChange) wasn't working inside the original code. But, once I put it inside DIV, they worked.

Here's the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Pd2yE8YvlNYU8HvgYTg?p=preview).

```
<div>
  <md-select placeholder="Favorite food" 
             [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" 
             name="food"
             (ngModelChange)="model=$event;updateModel2()"
            (change)="updateModel1()">
    <md-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>

  <p> Selected value: {{selectedValue}} </p>
</div>
```

I have created two separate functions, (change) calls updateModel1() and  (ngModelChange) calls updateModel2().